# Kan extension of conservative functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, kan-extension

Suppose the right Kan extension $\text{Ran}_F G$ of a conservative functor $F$ along a conservative functor $G$ exists (with the category $\text{dom} F=\text{dom} G$ not necessarily small).

Is it conservative itself?

Answer (score 2):

No, take $A$ to be any cocomplete category. For any category $I$ the right Kan extension of $Id:A\to A$ along the embedding $\iota:A\to Fun(I,A)$(object $a$ goes to the constant functor $\underline{a}$) is the colimit functor: $$Ran_{\iota} Id\cong \mathrm{colim}:Fun(I,A)\to A$$

Clearly, $Id$ and $\iota$ are conservative, but $\mathrm{colim}$ need not be conservative, e.g. take $A=\mathrm{vect}_k,I=X\rightarrow Y$. The colimit of $F:I\to A$ is $F(Y)$. There is a map of diagrams $\varphi:(k\xrightarrow{0}k)\to (0\xrightarrow{0}k)$ which induces $id:k\to k$ on colimits, but $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! What if I assume $F$ to preserve small limits?

Comment: In the example above $F=Id$ so it preserves small limits

Comment: Oh yes...Can you think of any case where this actually happens?

Comment: @MarkBehr I can't think of anything short of $G$ being an equivalence that would work.